# how to solve anti-leech in a better way?

Tags: apache, web

As I came across with the hot-leeching problem, I searched the website and found two ways to solve it. 
The first is an easier and simpler way with the code showing below:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}!^$ Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}!^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com(/)?.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule .*\.(gif¦jpg¦jpeg¦png¦swf)$ [mydomain.com...] [R,NC]"
```

This can only prevent some simple leeching ,but can do nothing with a determined person.

The other way is a better way with a script-and-cookies-based approach. They said "You set a cookie on an 'authorizated' page of your site, and then use a script to serve images only if the correct cookie is present in the image request. Images are kept in a directory accessible only to the script, and not via the Web. So, the script acts as an 'image server' on your site." I understand this principle but don't have any idea about how to realize it . Could anyone know how to realize this?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add some new lines to make the rewrite rules appear correctly? Code block must be preceded by a blank line.

Comment: thanks for your editorial advice. about this problem , is there any other way to solve this or it can't be solved perfectly? Thanks.

Comment: Note that many anti-hotlinking solutions will prevent your images appearing in image search engines unless you make specific arrangements to allow them access. This may be a good or a bad thing depending on your specific circumstances.

Comment: Thanks @snap. I never thought about that before,maybe I'll consider that later.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really give any implementation, but only some idea of how it can be achieved:

You will need a "portal" page, where you set the cookie for the user. Any request for resources without having a cookie of your site should be redirected here. There may not may not be a login mechanism here, depending on the purpose of your site, but usually you will set the cookie, after the user is logged in.

All resource links will link to to the same "script" page. The difference is that different resource will have different identifier (can be some sort of id - if you maintain a database of id to file path mapping). The identifier must be included in the query of the URL. The "script" will find the resource on the server based on the identifier (in case of id to file mapping, you will obtain the file path and go retrieve the file).

There will be a "script" page, which can be php code, for example. It will check for the cookie, then check for the identifier, then load the resource accordingly. You may also want to check for Referer to restrict the access a bit more (without checking, hot linking will work for any logged in user).

---

In this implementation, sharing a hot link to a resource will not work for any user that haven't visited the "portal" page (or haven't logged in, depending on your web site). It will also not work even for logged in user if they click the link from somewhere else.

However, scraping your website for resources is simple in both implementations mentioned in your question, since scraper can freely adjust the HTTP header.

Comment: Really thanks a lot . I am a little confused about the identifier. We set this for the anti-leeching or for something else? thanks again.

Comment: The identifier is to identify which resource to load. Otherwise, you will not know what to serve.